# Map displays above modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind css and flowbite and I want to display a modal, I am using this code for the [modal from flowbite](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/modal/) but the map somehow displays on top of my modal,
as you can see:
[image]

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 ml-8 bg-gray-100 w-screen h-screen ">
    <div name="left_side" class=" mt-6 mb-6 h-max ">
     <Modal/>
</div>
<div class="min-h-full">
        <Map /> (leaflet map)
    </div>
</div>
```

Can You please let me know any quick fix for this?

Comment: you're using the modal as a custom component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either modify the [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) for your map element to be lower, or increase the `z-index` value for your modal.

Try adding a similar class to following to your map element:

```
.map-element {
   z-index: -1;
}
```

To modify `z-index` for your modal, you can try adding it as an arbitrary value to your modal's class attribute:

```
<div class="z-[100]">
```

From tailwindcss documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/z-index#arbitrary-values

Comment: z-0 did the work. thank you